# How much bandwidth needed for bitcoin bigger blocks

Tags: blocksize, block-size-increase, bandwidth

If the Bitcoin blockchain would support 2000 transactions per second, how big would the blocks need to be (with segwit at 100% lets say), and most importantly, how much bandwidth would be necessary for a miner to propagate the blocks to 8 peers?

Comment: The very question is, "Bitcoin can be support the 2000 transactions per second?" so I think to exist other component work on bitcoin for improving transaction speed

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that Bitcoin currently does 2000 transactions each 10 minutes, you'll need blocks 600 times bigger, or more-or-less 1.2 GB each. Now you need bandwidth sufficient for that peer to transmit 9.6 GB each 10 minutes (1.2 GB * 8 peers -- I have no idea of what you meant by "necessary" bandwidth).

That's doable if you only have one miner in the entire network.